# std::uint32_t is not a type in c++11

Tags: c++11, cmake

I am using `std::uint32_t` as a type in `c++11` on a cmake project.
I added `set_property(cxx_compiler_flag "-std=c++11"` in `CMakeLists` but the error is still here.

Comment: And you do include [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) (where that type is defined)?

Comment: And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Adding <cstdint> worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can write:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

[CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD in cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html)

Use case:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(EventBusDev)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

[Live Example](https://github.com/gelldur/EventBus/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)

Also please remember to include [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)